# What is the performance difference between native 2d drawing api and html5 canvas API for iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have non-interactive 2d animation application using html5 canvas and it works great under desktop browsers but performance is miserable under iphone. How does the performance of iphone native [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_framework/_index.html) vs html5 canvas compare? Since the API is radically different before I spend all the efforts I am posting this question. Is there alternative native iphone API that is very similar to html5 canvas for 2d animations applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience: NO.
Mobile Safari has no real HTML Canvas Support, hence it's unbelievable slow. Native Stuff with Core Anmiation runs extremly well and won't have any troubles.